# Using a Typescript .d.ts file that doesn't declare a module

Tags: three.js, typescript, definitelytyped, tsd

I'm using tsd to download definitions from Definitely Typed and compile into a tsd.d.ts file. I haven't been able to build yet, but when I use an import like this:

```
import * as THREE from "three"
```

Visual Studio intellisense is happy. However, this doesn't work for [Detector.js](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/js/Detector.js) (a three.js library for detecting webgl support), with [this](https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/threejs/detector.d.ts) .d.ts file. I'm not sure what the issue is, but I did notice that the three.d.ts file exports
a module (THREE) and detector.d.ts file just exports an object:

three.d.ts

```
...
declare module 'three' {
    export=THREE;
}
```

detector.d.ts

```
interface DetectorStatic {
    canvas: boolean;
    webgl: boolean;
    workers: boolean;
    fileapi: boolean;

    getWebGLErrorMessage(): HTMLElement;
    addGetWebGLMessage(parameters?: {id?: string; parent?: HTMLElement}): void;
}

declare var Detector: DetectorStatic;
```

Does that change how I should be importing Detector?

Comment: Your question is very unclear. please provide a specific scenario and as many details as you can. code would also be good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a case like this, you can define your own.  For most projects I usually have an adhoc `.d.ts` file that I throw random declarations that I need (small interfaces, modules, whatever).

You should be able to simply define the module somewhere in your code.

```
declare module "path/to/detector" {
    export = DetectorStatic;
}
```

Comment: Ok. Thanks! That makes sense. Though, why doesn't the Definitely Typed file include this? Is there a different way to use `.d.ts` files that doesn't require the use of a module?

Comment: In my case, I'm not sure this answer is actually correct, but it was darned close. I've added a little detail to my question. What I found to work was:  
In the adhoc `custom.d.ts` file put  `declare module "Detector" {
    export = DetectorStatic;
}`  
In my tsd.d.ts file add a line:  `/// <reference path="custom.d.ts" />`.  
To import the file, use `import Detector = require("Detector");` instead of `import {Detector} from "Detector";` (Details on this last part [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/2242)).