# angular2 chrome extension chrome.runtime.sendMessage from typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to write a Chrome Extension using Angular 2.

In my `app.component.ts`, I have the following:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: 'app.component.html'
})
export class AppComponent {
  showHeading = true;
  heroes = ['Magneta', 'Bombasto', 'Magma', 'Tornado'];
  toggleHeading() {
    this.showHeading = !this.showHeading;
  }
  injectHello(){
    chrome.runtime.sendMessage({action:"inject"});
  }
}
```

The problem is that when I try to compile using [Ahead of Time compilation](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/aot-compiler.html), I get this error:

> Error at /dev/quickstart/app/app.component.ts:14:12:
>   Property 'runtime' does not exist on type 'typeof chrome'.

Apparently, my angular app does not know about chrome.runtime.  What is the best way to resolve this?

I've seen [this stack overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35096976/using-a-complex-d-ts-file-chrome-app-d-ts) about compiling chrome-app.d.ts with `tsc`, but I need to use [Ahead of Time compilation](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/aot-compiler.html) to get around the Content Security Policy.

Therefore, I use `node_modules/.bin/ngc -p tsconfig-aot.json` instead of `tsc`.  Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, fixed it.

Solution is in 3 parts.

1. First, I needed some extra files.  I put all of the following into a folder called `chrome`:
   [chrome-app.d.ts](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/chrome/chrome-app.d.ts)
   [index.d.ts](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/chrome/index.d.ts)
   [filesystem/index.d.ts](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/filesystem/index.d.ts) --> I renamed this to filesystem.d.ts
   [filewriter/index.d.ts](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/filewriter/index.d.ts) --> I renamed this to filewriter.d.ts

[image: file-structure]

2. There were a few modifications to the top comments in each to make the files know about each other:

   chrome-app.d.ts

> ```
> /// <reference path="index.d.ts"/>
> /// <reference path="filesystem.d.ts"/>
> ```

```
index.d.ts
/// <reference path="filesystem.d.ts" />


filesystem.d.ts
/// <reference path="filewriter.d.ts" />
```

3. Inside `app.component.ts`, I needed this at the top:
   `///<reference path="chrome/chrome-app.d.ts" />`
   import { Component } from '@angular/core';
4. To compile, I followed the [Angular 2 docs](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/aot-compiler.html):

   `node_modules/.bin/ngc -p tsconfig-aot.json`
   `node_modules/.bin/rollup -c rollup-config.js`

Voila

Comment: What is the content in the files? The links are broken