# How to use chrome-app.d.ts type in angular-cli 1.0.1 app?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-cli, definitelytyped

I've installed **@types/chrome** and add it in **tsconfig.app.json**

```
"types": [
  "chrome"
]
```

But when i use `chrome.app` in component, it show an error:

> Property 'app' does not exist on type 'typeof chrome'

**@types/chrome** folder contains **chrome-app.d.ts** is a file which i need, how can I refer to this

Source https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/types/chrome

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Since the creators of this typings definition module have chosen not to include the `chrome.app.*` definitions in the `index.d.ts` file of the `@types/chrome` module but instead separate them out into `chrome-app.d.ts`, you'll need to explicitly reference it in the file that uses those APIs:

`/// <reference types="chrome/chrome-app"/>`

Note that this must be at the top of the file, per the documentation for triple-slash directives in TypeScript:

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/triple-slash-directives.html

Also note that it should *not* be necessary to add a `"types": ["chrome"]` reference in your `tsconfig.json` file, as the latest version of the TypeScript compiler should *automatically* import all typings definition modules found in `node_modules/@types`. By adding this to your config, you are telling it to *only* import that one module. For more on this, you can refer to the config docs:

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html

Answer (score 1):

Just an update for Angular CLI nowadays (June 2018) (Angular 6) you can simply do:
**`npm i @types/chrome`**
and the error will go away.

Comment: Sometimes when cloning a repo, `npm i` doesn't do the trick. For some reason, I had to run `npm i @types/chrome` again, and then TS liked it.

Answer (score 0):

[This is what](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72881729/5235223) worked for me. This happened to me when I created a new angular project and then manually added content for the extension infrastructure. What resolved the issue was adding the following to tsconfig.json

```
...
"angularCompilerOptions": {
  "types": [ 'chrome'],
  ...
```