# Cannot find namespace/name chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to develop google extension, but found that I can't reference the `chrome` object without generating:

> ERROR in E:/ChromeExtensions/.../node_modules/chrome-promise/chrome-promise.d.ts (2160,66): Cannot find namespace 'chrome'.

or

> ERROR in E:/ChromeExtensions/.../src/app/chrome-tabs.servi
> ce.ts (14,7): Cannot find name 'chrome'.

I have added chrome typings `npm install --save @types/chrome` but it doesn't resolve build errors.

Any suggestions?

Comment: as a temporary fix is to use `window['chrome']`

Comment: Same issue here. Did you find a solution?

Comment: Nope, still using the temporary solution

Comment: Im keen to know a typed solution too :(

Comment: answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43655106/how-to-use-chrome-app-d-ts-type-in-angular-cli-1-0-1-app

Answer (score 32):

Based on [How to use chrome-app.d.ts type in angular-cli 1.0.1 app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43655106/how-to-use-chrome-app-d-ts-type-in-angular-cli-1-0-1-app)

1. I added `@types/chrome` to package.json
2. I added `/// <reference types="chrome"/>` to the top of my ts file

Answer (score 23):

### Update for 2019:

There's no need to use `/// <reference types="chrome"/>` anymore. `npm i -D @types/chrome` (and **reopening the project in VScode**) should be enough.

This sometimes happens when you clone a repo that already has a `@types` library installed. `npm i` doesn't get it done, but if you install the `@types` library again, it should work.

Comment: If VSCode is still complaining after installing the types, try restarting it.

Answer (score 12):

I am in the same case. I am creating a Chrome extension with Angular:

| Package | Version |
| --- | --- |
| @angular | 14.0.4 |
| @types/chrome | 0.0.193 |

I installed the Chrome types as shown in the documentation (https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/chrome):

```
npm install --save @types/chrome
```

And I added `chrome` to the `types` in the `tsconfig.app.json` file:

```json
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./out-tsc/app",
    "types": ["chrome"]
  },
  "...": "..."
}
```

After that, my code editor (PHPStorm) took the `chrome` keyword into account in my codes.

You can have several workspaces for a single project open in your code editor (https://angular.io/guide/file-structure), and you can configure the types needed for each workspace (in the `tsconfig.app.json` file). In this situation, your code editor will only take the types into account in the files of the relevant and configured workspace.

## Update 2023:

Here is the project on which I tested this configuration: https://github.com/jprivet-dev/chrome-extension-angular-starter-kit.

Comment: This is the most up-to-date answer

Comment: This also works for react, vite apps!

Answer (score 2):

It would nice to have a code snippet for context.

However, when I ran into this, it was because I was passing `chrome` into my function as an argument. It's silly to do that, however, since `chrome` is a global variable, and thus accessible from any file. Not only that, but since JavaScript objects are pass-by-reference, there's no need to pass around globals (you're editing the same object regardless).

TL;DR: Add `types/chrome` to `package.json`, and just access globals (i.e., `chrome` or `window`) from the file you're working in rather than passing it as an argument.

Passing `chrome` as argument (bad / unnecessary):

```
export function getItem(key: string, chromeStore: chrome): string {
  chromeStore.storage.local.get(key, (items: any) => {
    ...
  });
}
```

Using `chrome` as global (good):

```
export function getItem(key: string): string {
  chrome.storage.local.get(key, (items: any) => {
    ...
  });
}
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your answer, just a question, I am also passing it as an argument to a (factory) function, it feels more explicit to me. Could you elaborate on why this is bad practice? To be a bit more specific, I've got two different chrome objects I'm working with, one is in the nested scope of a callback .

Comment: Why do you have more than one chrome objects you're working w/? 

Also, since `chrome` is used as a singleton global object, how does that work to communicate between tabs or use `chrome.storage`?

Answer (score 1):

1. Install the chrome types using npm.
   npm install --save @types/chrome
2. Update your TypeScript configuration (usually found in tsconfig.app.json) by
   adding "chrome" to the "types" array:

```
     {
          "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
          "compilerOptions": {
            "outDir": "./out-tsc/app",
            "types": ["chrome"]
          },
          "files": "...",
          "include": "..."
        }
```

By adding "chrome" to the "types" array, you are instructing TypeScript to include typings for the Chrome API in your project. Save your changes and try rebuilding your TypeScript project. This should resolve any type-related issues you were facing when using Chrome-specific APIs.