# I cannot use chrome for communicating with extentions from angular

Tags: angular, google-chrome-extension

I am creating a project in angular for checking an extension is installed in browser. if not, I need to install it. For this, I'm using @types/chrome. I have installed it but cannot use in component.
when the first compiling it give this error and the second time it is working.
Any one can give me some help for this?

My code in component is:

```
chrome.runtime.sendMessage('pnepdmldkolfpooeokjpfagpaonbiikb', {
      openUrlInEditor: 'url'
    },
function (response) {
    if (!response)
    alert('not found')
});
```

> error: "error TS2304: Cannot find name 'chrome'."

Comment: error TS2339: Property 'chrome' does not exist on type 'Window'.
now this error occured..need any import??

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cannot find namespace/name chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47075437/cannot-find-namespace-name-chrome)

Comment: i already checked that answers..but my problem not solved