# Angular 6 Type Definition Not compiling

Tags: angular6

I am using Angular 6 and trying to call the mask function of the jquery.maskedinput javascript library in my ts file. The mask function in VS Code was not showing up or compiling so I found a type definition file and added it to the node_modules. Now intellitype finds the mask function and the squiggles go away. However I still get a compile error. What am I missing to have the page compile and use the mask function?

component.ts

```
 /// <reference path="../../../../node_modules/@types/maskedinput/index.d.ts"/>
.....
$("#dob").mask("99/99/9999", { placeholder: "mm/dd/yyyy" });
```

node_modules/@types/maskedinput/index.d.ts

```
interface JQuery {
mask(mask: string, options?: JQueryMaskedInputOptions): JQuery;
}
```

I am not sure what I am missing at this point. Any guidance will help.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer in another post with a similar issue [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43655106/how-to-use-chrome-app-d-ts-type-in-angular-cli-1-0-1-app.)

My issue was that I added the reference after my imports and not at the top of the page per documentation. Once I added the line below to the top of my component everything started working.

```
 /// <reference path="../../../../node_modules/@types/maskedinput/index.d.ts"/>
```

Documentation -
[Typescript Triple-Slash Directives](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/triple-slash-directives.html)